# Access GPU hardware specifications in Python?

Tags: python, cuda, gpu, nvidia, numba

I want to access various NVidia GPU specifications using Numba or a similar Python CUDA pacakge. Information such as available device memory, L2 cache size, memory clock frequency, etc.

From reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48654403/how-do-i-know-the-maximum-number-of-threads-per-block-in-python-code-with-either), I learned I can access some of the information (but not all) through Numba's CUDA device interface.

```py
from numba import cuda

device = cuda.get_current_device()
attribs = [s for s in dir(device) if s.isupper()]
for attr in attribs:
    print(attr, '=', getattr(device, attr))
```

Output on a test machine:

```
ASYNC_ENGINE_COUNT = 4
CAN_MAP_HOST_MEMORY = 1
COMPUTE_CAPABILITY = (5, 0)
MAX_BLOCK_DIM_X = 1024
MAX_BLOCK_DIM_Y = 1024
MAX_BLOCK_DIM_Z = 64
MAX_GRID_DIM_X = 2147483647
MAX_GRID_DIM_Y = 65535
MAX_GRID_DIM_Z = 65535
MAX_SHARED_MEMORY_PER_BLOCK = 49152
MAX_THREADS_PER_BLOCK = 1024
MULTIPROCESSOR_COUNT = 3
PCI_BUS_ID = 1
PCI_DEVICE_ID = 0
UNIFIED_ADDRESSING = 1
WARP_SIZE = 32
```

As you can see, I'm missing many fields listed [here](https://github.com/numba/numba/blob/master/numba/cuda/cudadrv/enums.py#L299) such as `TOTAL_CONSTANT_MEMORY`, `MAX_SHARED_MEMORY_PER_BLOCK`, `MEMORY_CLOCK_RATE`, and `MAX_THREADS_PER_MULTI_PROCESSOR`.

How can I view these values in Python?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All these values are lazily set to device object via `__getattr__` [method](https://github.com/numba/numba/blob/b3d09ff64367e3b002c606789496b82023de59e9/numba/cuda/cudadrv/driver.py#L264). You can access them with similar like in [this method](https://github.com/numba/numba/blob/b3d09ff64367e3b002c606789496b82023de59e9/numba/cuda/cudadrv/driver.py#L172). You need to dir not a device, but enums itself:

```
from numba.cuda.cudadrv import enums
from numba import cuda

device = cuda.get_current_device()
attribs= [name.replace("CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_", "") for name in dir(enums) if name.startswith("CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_")]
for attr in attribs:
    print(attr, '=', getattr(device, attr))
```