# How to find the number of cores in Google COLAB's GPU?

Tags: python, gpu, google-colaboratory

I want to know the number of cores in Colab's assigned GPU. I have used `!nvidia-smi -q` but it is showing all other details but not showing the number of cores of the GPU.

I have researched about it but didn't find it.
Any help regarding this!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easy way out would be to run the `!nvidia-smi` command to get all the GPU information. There seem to be 2 possible options on the cards that you will get after that - K80 or T4, the *K80 has 4992 CUDA cores* while the *T4 has 2560 CUDA cores* (Found this using Google).

If you still need scripts to find out the number of cores though, you can find those scripts in [this answer (python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63823395/how-can-i-get-the-number-of-cuda-cores-in-my-gpu-using-python-and-numba) and [this answer (C)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32530604/how-can-i-get-number-of-cores-in-cuda-device). I would still suggest the much simpler way of looking up the CUDA cores for that particular model.

On a sidenote, there are [instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48750199/google-colaboratory-misleading-information-about-its-gpu-only-5-ram-available) where users only get 5% of the GPU ram accessible to them. I have not faced this problem but you should still check the Volatile GPU Util that is shown in the `!nvidia-smi` command (0% is what should be expected when nothing is running).